# Error 400: invalid_scope ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.reporting.audit"] unable to set up email monitor with googleAPI python client

Tags: python, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client, google-email-audit-api

I began following the [code sample](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/samples/audit/audit.py) given on **googleapis** github page to help me understand how the [Email audit](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit) API works.

The sample initialized the API service like this:

```
from googleapiclient import sample_tools

service, flags = sample_tools.init(
    argv,
    "audit",
    "v1",
    __doc__,
    __file__,
    scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps/reporting/audit.readonly",
)
```

Since for my purposes, I'll need read AND write permissions, I included the scope as 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps/reporting/audit'

Here's how I am trying to initialize the service:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import os

SCOPES = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.reporting.audit'
    ]

creds = None

if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

#now attempting to initialize the audit service

auditService = build('audit', 'v1', credentials=creds)
```

Now, I am facing two issues here:

- I can't access the given scope
  After I am prompted to authorize the scopes by logging in to my admin account, I am shown the following message:

> Authorization Error
> Error 400:
> invalid_scope
> Some requested scopes cannot be shown: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.reporting.audit]

- For testing, if I only request readonly scopes, I get:

> googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: audit  version: v1

Can someone please guide me through how to properly set up an email monitor using googleapis python client? (Is the given sample on github outdated?)

Answer (score 0):

The [sample code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/samples/audit/audit.py) mentioned actually refers to the (now deprecated) Enterprise Activity API. This service was moved to [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/overview) and as Enterprise Activity API, it is only available for Workspace domains.

So indeed, this script is outdated. If you want to use `Reports API` to manage `Activities`, you may want to refer to the python quickstart [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/quickstart/python).

The end goal of your script is unclear, however as you’ve mentioned you’d like to use Email Audit API, I’d recommend [following this guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit#types_of_users_in_a_monitored_email_scenario) to confirm if this is the right API for your demand. Keep in mind that this API is also only available for Workspace Domains.

Alternatively, I’d also recommend having a look at [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides) capabilities to see if it fits your needs.